# How to calculate tf-idf when working on .txt files in python 3.7?

Tags: pdf, nlp, python-3.7, tf-idf

I have books in pdf and I want to do NLP tasks such as preprocessing, tf-idf calculation, word2vec, etc on those books. So I converted them into .txt files and was trying to get tf-idf scores. Previously I performed tf-idf on a CSV file, so I made some changes in that code and tried to use it for .txt file. But I am unsuccessful in my attempt.

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
data = open('jungle book.txt', 'r+')
# print(data.read())
cvec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', min_df=1, max_df=.5, ngram_range=(1,2))
cvec.fit(data)
list(islice(cvec.vocabulary_.items(), 20))
len(cvec.vocabulary_)
cvec_count = cvec.transform(data)
print('Sparse Matrix Shape : ', cvec_count.shape)
print('Non Zero Count : ', cvec_count.nnz)
print('sparsity: %.2f%%' % (100 * cvec_count.nnz / (cvec_count.shape[0] * cvec_count.shape[1])))

occ = np.asarray(cvec_count.sum(axis=0)).ravel().tolist()
count_df = pd.DataFrame({'term': cvec.get_feature_names(), 'occurrences' : occ})
term_freq = count_df.sort_values(by='occurrences', ascending=False).head(20)
print(term_freq)
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
transformed_weights = transformer.fit_transform(cvec_count)
weights = np.asarray(transformed_weights.mean(axis=0)).ravel().tolist()
weight_df = pd.DataFrame({'term' : cvec.get_feature_names(), 'weight' : weights})
tf_idf = weight_df.sort_values(by='weight', ascending=False).head(20)
print(tf_idf)
```

This code is working until print ('Non Zero Count :', cvec_count.shape) and printing:

> Sparse Matrix Shape :  (0, 7132)
>
> Non Zero Count :  0

Then it is giving error:

> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Even if I run this code with ignoring ZeroDivisionError, still it is wrong as it is not counting any frequencies.

I have no idea how to work around .txt file. What is the proper way to work on .txt file for NLP tasks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because data variable is empty or wrong type. Just opening the text file is not enough. You have to read the contents into a string variable and then do the preprocessing on that variable. Try replacing

```
data = open('jungle book.txt', 'r+')
# print(data.read())
```

with

```
with open('jungle book.txt', 'r') as file:
     data = file.read()
```